# Вывод статей с категориями и количеством комментариев одним запросом

Tags: sql

Есть таблица articles со статьями. 
Есть таблица category с категориями. Они связаны связью многие ко многим, т.е. у каждой статьи может быть несколько категорий.
Есть таблица с комментариями, которая связана с articles связью один ко многим.
Нужно вывести одним запросом все статьи с категориями и количеством комментариев к каждой. 
Категории идут в одном поле типа: Категория1,Категория2 через GROUP_CONCAT

Пытаюсь вывести так:

```
SELECT articles.id, title, articles.date, articles.date_edited, articles.author, article_formats.name as article_format, image_intro, image_main, video_id, text_intro, text_main, GROUP_CONCAT( category.name) as category, GROUP_CONCAT( category.id) as cat_id, COUNT( comments.id) as comments_count
  FROM articles
  LEFT JOIN article_formats ON (article_formats.id = articles.article_format)
  LEFT JOIN articles_category ON (articles.id = articles_category.article_id)
  LEFT JOIN category ON (category.id = articles_category.category_id)
  LEFT JOIN comments ON (articles.id = comments.article_id)
  GROUP BY articles.id
  ORDER BY articles.id DESC
  LIMIT " .NUMBER_OF_ARTICLES. " OFFSET $offset
```

Все выводит, но с дублированием: категорий и неправильным количеством комментов.

Надеюсь все понятно объяснил...

UPDATE Выводит:

```
  ["category"]=>
  string(503) "категория 1,категория 1,категория 1,категория 1,категория 1,категория 1,категория 1,категория 1,категория 3,категория 3,категория 3,категория 3,категория 3,категория 3,категория 3,категория 3,категория 5,категория 5,категория 5,категория 5,категория 5,категория 5,категория 5,категория 5"
  ["cat_id"]=>
  string(47) "1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3"
  ["comments_count"]=>
  string(2) "24"
```

Это проблемное место в выводе. В этой статье 8 комментов и 3 категории

По поводу IDE я не очень разбираюсь. Такой скриншот не подойдет?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пкажите что запрос выводит.

Comment: ["category"]=>
      string(503) "категория 1,категория 1,категория 1,категория 1,категория 1,категория 1,категория 1,категория 1,категория 3,категория 3,категория 3,категория 3,категория 3,категория 3,категория 3,категория 3,категория 5,категория 5,категория 5,категория 5,категория 5,категория 5,категория 5,категория 5"
      ["cat_id"]=>
      string(47) "1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3"
      ["comments_count"]=>
      string(2) "24"


(Это проблемное место в выводе. В этой статье 8 комментов и 3 категории)

Comment: выполните запрос в IDE и приложите скриншот.

Comment: Уберите comments из основного запроса. вы получите правильный список категорий. после этого оберните запрос в еще один select и уже к нему джоинете комментарии (можно заранее сгруппировать комментарии до article_id). выходит что то вроде `select * from (ваш-запрос-без-comments) x left join (select article_id, count(1) comments_count from comments group by article_id) y on x.id=y.article_id order by ... limit ...`

Comment: Спасибо Mike, но не могу совладать с синтаксисом. А нельзя ли более подробно запрос расписать? Я слаб в sql (